# How to remove data from or empty a cursor in PLSQL Oracle Procedure?

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor

I want to fetch some rows from a table into a cursor and after doing my desired work,I want to empty the cursor so that I can use the cursor again. the whole process will be inside an loop. I have searched for this many times but I am not getting my desired post. I think I have made myself clear what do I want. In short, I want to treat my cursor as an ArrayList in Java.

Comment: Well did you check the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/explicit_cursor.htm#LNPLS01313), you may `OPEN`, `FETCH`and `CLOSE`a cursor...

Comment: Cursor cannot be deleted once generated. You need a collection rather.

Comment: A requirement to execute looped processing in PL/SQL is always an amber flag, especially for people with a Java or similar background (no offence). SQL is a set-oriented paradigm and PL/SQL works best when it works with sets too. So you may to provide a bit more detail about what data you're selecting for this cursor and how you intend to process it inside this loop. If you do so we can help you with the most effective implementation.

Comment: Hi, the data is not that complex. For example, a table of Food Price. I have a query like 'select * from price where amount < 500'. So it may result in multiple rows. And then I want to remove a specific row from Cursor. Though I have implemented a solution with arrays. But I wanna hear something from you too.

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated you need to fetch your cursor into a collection (or don't use an explicit cursor and BULK COLLECT directly with INTO (see below).  Once you have it in a collection you can iterate through and delete entries that meet some requirement.  PL/SQL collections have first and next functions that work together like an Iterator in Java so you can delete entries as you loop through them.

```
DECLARE

  -- table definition
  TYPE t_obj_tab IS TABLE OF all_objects%ROWTYPE;
  v_obj_tab t_obj_tab;

  -- local variables
  v_index INTEGER;
BEGIN

  -- get some data into a collection
  SELECT *
    BULK COLLECT
    INTO v_obj_tab
    FROM all_objects
   WHERE rownum <= 500;

  -- log the count for demonstration
  dbms_output.put_line(v_obj_tab.count);

  -- get the index of the first element in the collection
  v_index := v_obj_tab.first;

  -- loop through the collection
  WHILE v_index IS NOT NULL
  LOOP

    -- delete objects with some criteria
    IF v_obj_tab(v_index).object_name LIKE '%E%' THEN
      v_obj_tab.delete(v_index);
    END IF;

    -- get next element of collection
    v_index := v_obj_tab.next(v_index);
  END LOOP;

  -- log the count to see if any were deleted
  dbms_output.put_line(v_obj_tab.count);
END;
/
-- 500
-- 206
```

You should be aware that pulling a large amount of objects into a collection will use a proportional amount of memory.  PL/SQL collections should aim to be small when possible (personally I like 500 rows for bulk processing, but you should benchmark).  It would be advisable to, instead of pulling data and filtering it procedurally, use SQL to filter the results to only return the rows you are interested in (as others also mentioned).

I think you were also asking how to process the same set of data multiple times.  If you want to do that you can make a second collection variable, set it to the first (which makes a copy) and keep that as the original set.  When you are done processing you can use that to get the original rows and do some different processing to them.

```
DECLARE

  -- table definition
  TYPE t_obj_tab IS TABLE OF all_objects%ROWTYPE;
  v_obj_tab   t_obj_tab;
  v_obj_tab_2 t_obj_tab;

  -- local variables
  v_index INTEGER;
BEGIN

  -- get some data into a collection
  SELECT *
    BULK COLLECT
    INTO v_obj_tab
    FROM all_objects
   WHERE rownum <= 500;

  -- copy!
  v_obj_tab_2 := v_obj_tab;

  -- log the count for demonstration
  dbms_output.put_line(v_obj_tab.count);

  -- get the index of the first element in the collection
  v_index := v_obj_tab.first;

  -- loop through the collection
  WHILE v_index IS NOT NULL
  LOOP

    -- delete objects with some criteria
    IF v_obj_tab(v_index).object_name LIKE '%E%' THEN
      v_obj_tab.delete(v_index);
    END IF;

    -- get next element of collection
    v_index := v_obj_tab.next(v_index);
  END LOOP;

  -- log the count to see if any were deleted
  dbms_output.put_line(v_obj_tab.count);
  dbms_output.put_line(v_obj_tab_2.count);
END;
/
-- 500
-- 206
-- 500 (copy count)
```